# Bokeh: How to access Index with custom callback in HoverTool for a line?

Tags: python, bokeh

I try to make a JSCallback for a line and access the index of it.
For the `circle()` glyph, this works if I precisely hover over the dot. In this case, the Hover annotation works and the `cb_data['index'].indices` holds the same value as the hover annotation shows.  However, for the `line()` with `mode='vline'`, this does not work. Even when the internal hover annotation shows an index, the `cb_data['index'].indices` is empty.
Below is a minimal working example that shows this case in the console log of the browser:

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import layout

plot1 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=250)
plot2 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=250)

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                   "Value1":[0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700], 
                   "Value2":[0, 1, 2, 4,8 , 16, 32, 64]})
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

line = plot1.line(x='ID', y='Value1', source=source)
circle = plot2.circle(x='ID', y='Value2', source=source)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), 
                        code="""
                        console.log("Indices: "+ cb_data['index'].indices);
                        console.log("Mouse X: "+ cb_data['geometry'].x);
                        console.log("Mouse Y: "+ cb_data['geometry'].y);
                        """)

hover_tool_plot = HoverTool(mode='vline', callback=callback)

plot1.add_tools(hover_tool_plot)
plot2.add_tools(hover_tool_plot)

layout_ = layout([[plot1],[plot2]])
curdoc().add_root(layout_)
```

[image]
When I hover between the two points 5 and 6, the hover annotation snaps to the index 6. However, the output looks as follows, which means there is no index selected:

```
Indices: 
VM612:6 Mouse X: 5.642537313432836
VM612:7 Mouse Y: 469.12556053811653
```

For the circle case, this does work (But as I said, only if I hover exactly over the point).
[image]
The output of the log indeed gives me the index 6.

```
Indices: 6
VM746:6 Mouse X: 5.995974576271187
VM746:7 Mouse Y: 32.473542600896856
```

Is there any way to get the correct index when hovering over the line using the `mode='vline'`?
I do need the index in the callback to set a line in another plot for my application.
PS: I´m running Bokeh as a server application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a line glyph, you want to look at [`.line_indices`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/selections.html?highlight=line_indices#bokeh.models.selections.Selection.line_indices), not  `.indices`.

Note that there is no one "correct" answer about which index (previous? next? nearest?) should be returned. The hover tool has a [`line_policy`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html?highlight=line_policy#bokeh.models.tools.HoverTool.line_policy) setting that you can customize you your needs.

Comment: Thanks very much! That's what I was looking for. However it seems, that  `.line_indices` always holds the previous sample index, no matter which `line_policy` I set for the HoverTool. The actual annotation box with the information shows the 'correct' index (meaning the specifically set policy-type index), but `cb_data['index'].line_indices` does not. Can you confirm this or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't confirm offhand, but thinking about it more it would make sense for the API property to behave that way, since the "interp" line policy would not have a meaningful interpretation there.